# I=x-1 J=x+1 ideal of ring Z [x] ,I+J=Z[x]

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I=(x-1) J=(x+1) ideals of ring Z [x] , 
 How can i demonstrate  I+J=Z[x]? 
Probably I+J won't be equal to Z [x].

Comment: What do you think $I+J$ means? Which elements do you _know_ are in $I+J$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

You should think: which elements can we get inside an ideal, like $I$? Which elements can we get inside a sum of ideals, like $I+J$?

Then, $I+J=\mathbb Z[x]$ will be true if and only if $1\in I+J$, can you see why?

Do you know of some result which could help you in determining if $1$ is in $I+J$?